# How to create the output pattern of this example by concatenating string in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have this code in R:

```
for (i in 0:4) {
    for (j in i:4) {
        b<-paste0("Y1 = ",i," && Y2 = ",j,",") 
        a<-paste0("X",i:j,"+")  
        print(paste0(b,a))
    }
}
Output:
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 0,X0+"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 1,X0+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 1,X1+"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 2,X0+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 2,X1+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 2,X2+"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 3,X0+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 3,X1+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 3,X2+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 3,X3+"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4,X0+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4,X1+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4,X2+" "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4,X3+"
[5] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4,X4+"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 1,X1+"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 2,X1+" "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 2,X2+"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 3,X1+" "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 3,X2+" "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 3,X3+"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4,X1+" "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4,X2+" "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4,X3+" "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4,X4+"
[1] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 2,X2+"
[1] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 3,X2+" "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 3,X3+"
[1] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 4,X2+" "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 4,X3+" "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 4,X4+"
[1] "Y1 = 3 && Y2 = 3,X3+"
[1] "Y1 = 3 && Y2 = 4,X3+" "Y1 = 3 && Y2 = 4,X4+"
[1] "Y1 = 4 && Y2 = 4,X4+"
```

**Expected output**:

```
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 0, X0,"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 1, X0+X1,"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 2, X0+X1+X2,"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 3, X0+X1+X2+X3,"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4, X0+X1+X2+X3+X4,"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 2, X0+X2,"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 3, X0+X3,"
[1] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4, X0+X4,"

[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 1, X1,"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 2, X1+X2,"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 3, X1+X2+X3,"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4, X1+X2+X3+X4,"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 3, X1+X3,"
[1] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4, X1+X4,"

[1] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 2, X2,"
[1] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 3, X2+X3,"
[1] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 4, X2+X3+X4,"
[1] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 4, X2+X4,"

[1] "Y1 = 3 && Y2 = 3, X3,"
[1] "Y1 = 3 && Y2 = 4, X3+X4,"

[1] "Y1 = 4 && Y2 = 4, X4,"
```

My goal is to generate an output exactly like the "Expected output:" block. The code you build presents a solution not very close to the expected result, but I believe it is on the right track. I just don't know how to solve this loop problem. Any ideas, considering that the code should be generic. in this example I used a loop of 0:4, but it could be 0:1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. One big thins is you need to specify a `collapse` argument to `paste0()` if you want it to return a single `character` string. Also it seems like you wanted an extra space after the comma in `b` so I added that in.
The other main thing is you needed something to get the extra combinations of `X` values that *don't* include `i:j`. Here I used a conditional `if` statement to only induce that loop to iterate through the remaining values if `i` is less than `top - 2` where `top` is the endpoint of the outer loop.

```r
# empty list to catch results
results <- list()

# set upper limit of loop
top <- 4

# loop and assign output to results
for (i in 0:top) {
  for (j in i:top) {
    b <- paste0("Y1 = ",i," && Y2 = ",j,", ")
    a <- paste0("X",i:j, collapse = "+")
    
    results <- append(results, paste0(b,a,",", collapse = " "))
  }
  if (i < (top - 1)) {
    for (k in (i + 2):top) {
      c <- paste0("X",i,"+","X",k)
      results <- append(results, paste0(b,c, ",", collapse = " "))
    }
  }
}


cbind(results)
#>       results                            
#>  [1,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 0, X0,"            
#>  [2,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 1, X0+X1,"         
#>  [3,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 2, X0+X1+X2,"      
#>  [4,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 3, X0+X1+X2+X3,"   
#>  [5,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4, X0+X1+X2+X3+X4,"
#>  [6,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4, X0+X2,"         
#>  [7,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4, X0+X3,"         
#>  [8,] "Y1 = 0 && Y2 = 4, X0+X4,"         
#>  [9,] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 1, X1,"            
#> [10,] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 2, X1+X2,"         
#> [11,] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 3, X1+X2+X3,"      
#> [12,] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4, X1+X2+X3+X4,"   
#> [13,] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4, X1+X3,"         
#> [14,] "Y1 = 1 && Y2 = 4, X1+X4,"         
#> [15,] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 2, X2,"            
#> [16,] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 3, X2+X3,"         
#> [17,] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 4, X2+X3+X4,"      
#> [18,] "Y1 = 2 && Y2 = 4, X2+X4,"         
#> [19,] "Y1 = 3 && Y2 = 3, X3,"            
#> [20,] "Y1 = 3 && Y2 = 4, X3+X4,"         
#> [21,] "Y1 = 4 && Y2 = 4, X4,"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: So, in the "Expected output" I present in lines 6:8; 13:14 and 18, some configurations that I couldn't generate with the loop I created. the biggest part of the problem you solved and i am grateful. But I couldn't think of how to return the lines in question, I know the code is not complete, because I don't know how to assemble it, this was the closest I could get.

Comment: Ok, thanks for highlighting those lines, I'll have to think about that bit. But what about `vmin2` etc from your comment? I'm confused by that part.

Comment: For the first part, I think you could add an `if` statement to conditionally add a step in the inner loop for `X0+X2` etc.

Comment: Sorry, it was my confusion, I didn't realize the correct is: "Y=0 && Y=2, X0+X2,"; [1] "Y=0 && Y=3, X0+X3,"; [1] "Y=0 && Y=4, X0+X4,"; [1] "Y=1 && Y=3, X1+X3,"; [1] "Y=1 && Y=4, X1+X4," ; [1] "Y=2 && Y=4, X2+X4,". Referring to the lines mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: About, If. I thought about this possibility, but when I scale to 1000 instead of 4, for example, this solution seems to be unfeasible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246757/discussion-between-cnauber-and-dan-adams).